# Play Store Not Downloading Large Apps

Tags: google-play-store, cyanogenmod, downloading, 4.3-jelly-bean

When I try to download any large app from the Play Store (v 4.3.11), it stays at "downloading" and doesn't go anywhere. I'm able to download small apps such as Angry Birds without a problem.

My GApps is version 4.3 gapps-jb-20130813. I'm using CyanogenMod 10.2 (Android 4.3) Nightly on a Droid 4.

Answer (score 1):

Is it on auto-update? In the Google Play settings, make sure `Auto-update apps` is set to `Auto-update apps at any time. Data charges may apply.`

Answer (score 0):

Since many phones have lower memory and the Android OS is designed to kill apps that are in the background for a while when it needs memory for foreground apps - it is common practice for the OS to kill the Google Play app as well, even while it is still downloading an app (it will usually be later restarted and the downloading of apps will resume).

This can be solved by keeping Google Play in the foreground while your preferred app is being downloaded.